# Magnolia Blossom : Two pages sharing the same area

Tags: spring, content-management-system, freemarker, area, magnolia

I'm using the Magnolia Spring Integration (Blossom) for my web app and I definitely don't understand how (if it's even possible) to share a unique area between two pages.

This is how I've worked so far :

- I have three templates `main-template`, `template-1` and `template-2`.
- `template-1` and `template-2` both redirect to `main-template` by redefining their own *"body"* areas.
- In the class of `template-1` I have three areas : `content-area`, `area-1` and `area-2`
- In the script of `template-1` I include the three areas with the following directives : `[@cms.area name="content-area"/]`, `[@cms.area name="area-1"/]`
  and
  `[@cms.area name="area-2"/]`
- The same areas are defined in the `template-2` class and script

What I want is to share, lets say, `area-1` between `template-1` and `template-2`. The problem is that by redefining them in each class they are considered like different areas...
Through my tests and the magnolia documentation, what I understand is that an area can only be defined within a template class so it can be accessed in the script of this template and only the areas defined directly in the template class associated with the page will be process/rendered.
No matter what I try, as long as the areas are not defined in the page's template class they cannot be accessed and therefore included pages don't have their areas rendered.
Does anyone have a clue in how I can "include" or process "areas" from other templates in another one ? Or am I doing it all wrong ?

Thank you for your time.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is still a valid question, so let me answer it:
As far as I know areas can inherit from other areas (normal Java class inheritance using "extends ..."). As far as I know this wasn't available in 2013 yet, but it is now. I know this because I filed this as a feature request once and it was marked as solved at some point, and I think I also successfully used it once (don't remember clearly).

If for some reason it's still not possible to extend areas from super classes, then you could still use conventional tools like putting the logic to a helper class and making the actual areas very slim (that is just calls into the shared helper class). And the actual template (.jsp or .ftl file) can be shared anyway.